# 'docker.io' has no installation candidate on my GCP Virtual Machine

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am trying to install docker on my GCP's VM in order to run a script using selenium on my VM following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/C9wLQiX9UoQ?t=608). However after

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo apt install docker.io
```

I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker.io is not available, but is referred to 
by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obs
oleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'docker.io' has no installation candidate
```

None of the solutions I found on the Internets enabled me to cope with this issue, do you know how I can install docker on my GCP VM?

Let me know if you need any details about my VM, ...

Here are my os name and version:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
VERSION_CODENAME=stretch
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Here is my Linux kernel version:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ uname -r
4.9.0-12-amd64
```

## Update

I am now following [docs.docker.com documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/). But I have an issue when installing docker engine:

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli co
ntainerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package docker-ce is not available, but is referred to by another pack
age.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'
```

Sorted! Thanks to Lawrence Cherone and all of you!

Comment: Avoid incoherent outdated yt tuts and follow (copy/paste) the official documentation for installing on linux: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: What is your OS version? Appears to be Ubuntu or Debian. Why do you want to install an old version? Follow the installation instructions for your OS: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with some commands outputs that might answer your question.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

Comment: Did you read the documentation link provided? `docker.io` is an old package. Why do you want to use unsupported, old software versions?

Comment: @JohnHanley I've just received the link, I can't read that fast
I want to use what is right for my machine, and the only documentation I had so far was the video I provided.

Comment: Your new update means that you did not complete the previous steps correctly or they failed. Double-check this command: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid incoherent outdated YouTube tutorials and follow (copy/paste) the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/). Be sure that you followed all the required steps and ran all the  required commands.